# SQL Server 2017 vs SQL Server 2012 performance problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-performance, sql-server-2017

I have SQL code that is run on SQL Server 2017 in less than 200 ms, but the same code on SQL Server 2012 takes more than 3 seconds - can anyone tell me:

1. why is this happening
2. how do I solve it

```
select count(*) from dbo.mConsultationQuestionsReplies = 1,300,000
```

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @maxCount int;
DECLARE @ddlIds nvarchar(max);
SET @maxCount = 6;
SET @ddlIds = '4,8,840,779,10,813,3,18,7,918';


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#rList') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #rList

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#docList') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #docList

SELECT
    rd.UserID, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ids1.value IS NULL
           THEN CAST(ids2.value AS int) 
           ELSE CAST(ids1.value AS int) 
     END) [cid] 
INTO
    #docList 
FROM
    mDJDoctors [rd] 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.[mDJDoctorsSpeciality] [rs] ON rd.DoctorID = rs.doctorId
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.mDJSpecialtyCategory [rca] ON rca.SpecialtyId = rs.specialId
LEFT JOIN 
    STRING_SPLIT(@ddlIds, ',') [ids1] ON rca.CategoryId = ids1.value
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.mDJDoctorsSpecialtyAbove [ars] ON ars.doctorId = rd.DoctorID
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.mDJSpecialtyAboveCategory [arca] ON arca.AboveSpecialtyId = ars.SpecialtyAboveId
LEFT JOIN
    STRING_SPLIT(@ddlIds, ',') [ids2] ON [arca].CategoryId = ids2.value
WHERE
    [ids1].value IS NOT NULL
    OR [ids2].value IS NOT NULL

SELECT * 
INTO #rList 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.cid ORDER BY t.ReplyDateInsert DESC) AS rowNumber 
     FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT r.ReplyUserID, r.ReplyDateInsert, d.cid
          FROM dbo.mConsultationQuestionsReplies[r] 
          JOIN #docList [d] ON r.ReplyUserID = d.UserID
          WHERE r.ReplyId IN (SELECT MAX(r.ReplyId)[id]
                              FROM dbo.mConsultationQuestionsReplies[r]
                              JOIN #docList [d] on r.ReplyUserID = d.UserID
                              GROUP BY d.cid, d.UserID)) [t]) [t] 
WHERE
    t.rowNumber <= @maxCount

SELECT 
    u.FirstName AS DoctorName,
    u.UserID AS DoctorUserId,
    sp.specialFaName AS DoctorSpecialty,
    ab.SpecialtyAboveFaName AS DoctorAboveSpecialty,
    md.DoctorGUID,
    md.DoctorID,
    cp.ProfileISOnline,
    p.ProfilePicture AS DoctorProfilePicture,
    p.ProfileDateInserted,
    r.ReplyDateInsert AS LastReplyDateInsert,
    r.cid
FROM 
    dbo.mDJDoctors AS md
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Core_Users AS u ON md.UserID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Core_Profiles AS p ON u.UserID = p.UserID
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM #rList) [r] ON r.ReplyUserID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.mConsultationDocterProfile AS cp ON cp.UserID = u.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.mDJDoctorsSpeciality AS mdad ON md.DoctorID = mdad.doctorId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.mDJSpecialty AS sp ON mdad.specialId = sp.specialId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.mDJDoctorsSpecialtyAbove AS mdad2 ON md.DoctorID = mdad2.doctorId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.mDJSpecialtyAbove AS ab ON mdad2.SpecialtyAboveId = ab.SpecialtyAboveId
WHERE 
    cp.ProfileISOnline = 1
```

update : 
base on guid from marc-s , i removed STRING_SPLIT and new result is

```
declare @maxCount int;
set @maxCount = 6;


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#rList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #rList
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#docList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #docList

select rd.UserID, (case when arca.CategoryId is null then cast(rca.CategoryId as int) else cast(arca.CategoryId as int) end)[cid] into #docList 
from mDJDoctors [rd]   WITH (NOLOCK)
left join dbo.[mDJDoctorsSpeciality] [rs]  WITH (NOLOCK) on rd.DoctorID = rs.doctorId
left join dbo.mDJSpecialtyCategory [rca]  WITH (NOLOCK) on rca.SpecialtyId = rs.specialId
left join dbo.mDJDoctorsSpecialtyAbove [ars]  WITH (NOLOCK) on ars.doctorId = rd.DoctorID
left join dbo.mDJSpecialtyAboveCategory [arca]  WITH (NOLOCK) on arca.AboveSpecialtyId = ars.SpecialtyAboveId
where arca.CategoryId in (4,8,840,779,10,813,3,18,7,918) or rca.CategoryId in (4,8,840,779,10,813,3,18,7,918)


select  * into #rList from (
select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.cid ORDER BY t.ReplyDateInsert DESC) AS rowNumber from (
select distinct r.ReplyUserID, r.ReplyDateInsert, d.cid
from dbo.mConsultationQuestionsReplies[r]  WITH (NOLOCK) 
join #docList [d] on r.ReplyUserID = d.UserID
where r.ReplyId in(
select max(r.ReplyId)[id]
  from dbo.mConsultationQuestionsReplies[r]  WITH (NOLOCK)
  join #docList [d] on r.ReplyUserID = d.UserID
group by d.cid,d.UserID
))[t])[t] where t.rowNumber <= @maxCount

    SELECT distinct
           u.FirstName AS DoctorName,
           u.UserID AS DoctorUserId,
           sp.specialFaName AS DoctorSpecialty,
           ab.SpecialtyAboveFaName AS DoctorAboveSpecialty,
           md.DoctorGUID,
           md.DoctorID,
           cp.ProfileISOnline,
           p.ProfilePicture AS DoctorProfilePicture,
           p.ProfileDateInserted,
           r.ReplyDateInsert AS LastReplyDateInsert,
           r.cid

    FROM dbo.mDJDoctors AS md  WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN dbo.Core_Users AS u  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON md.UserID = u.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Core_Profiles AS p  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON u.UserID = p.UserID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            select * from #rList
        ) [r] 
            ON r.ReplyUserID = u.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.mConsultationDocterProfile AS cp  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON cp.UserID = u.UserID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.mDJDoctorsSpeciality AS mdad  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON md.DoctorID = mdad.doctorId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.mDJSpecialty AS sp  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON mdad.specialId = sp.specialId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.mDJDoctorsSpecialtyAbove AS mdad2  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON md.DoctorID = mdad2.doctorId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.mDJSpecialtyAbove AS ab  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON mdad2.SpecialtyAboveId = ab.SpecialtyAboveId
    WHERE cp.ProfileISOnline = 1
    order by cid, LastReplyDateInsert
```

its take 200 ms in sql 2017 and take 1038ms in sql 2012

update 3:
this i my execution plans xml for 2012 and 2017

[2012 and 2017 execution plans](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wONec7tsorOwd37y7zjvjoSlKEfDtrfZ)

update 4:
[server config](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EJ20YMwcOPOa6oTM2PsN-mV4y8in-vlG)

Comment: Using the `STRING_SPLIT`, this **cannot possibly** run on SQL Server 2012.. (this is a **new function** in SQL Server **2017** and newer); or you have a self-made replacement for `STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2012 -> then this would be my first guess (and my first point to investigate)

Comment: i have create STRING_SPLIT function in 2012 .

Comment: As I said - that would be the **first place** to thoroughly investigate! You can easily time some tests using your `STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2012, and the built-in version of SQL Server 2017 - are they performing similarly?....

Comment: tanx dude i will remove this function . can you plz looking for any other problem

Comment: Maybe you should look at the answer of this post:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227946/random-insane-bad-execution-plans-in-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: i am executing sql cmd on sql server manager so there is no any bad plan, its will be create best plan run time . but i need to say execution plan in sql server 2012 is different from 2017

Comment: OT: unless this is a read only database,  remove those  WITH (NOLOCK) unless you want incorrect data.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server 2012 database is missing an index (compared to SQL Server 2017) on [dbo].[Core_Profiles]

For SQL Server 2012, there is no index on `[dbo].[Core_Profiles].Userid` and although the query has only 52 distinct userids, it scans the full `[Core_Profiles]` table (~0.5mil rows) to hash match it with 52 rows and return: 52 rows (the scale diff is considerable).

For SQL Server 2017, there is the `[missing_index_9245_9243]` (which also includes the ProfilePicture{?}). Instead of half million table scan, it performs a 52 rows/times loops join. There is still a keylookup to [Core_Profiles] for the retrieval of ProfileDateInserted.

The first thing to try, would be to create an index on `[dbo].[Core_Profiles].Userid`. Whether you choose to include the ProfilePicture is a bit irrelevant to the particular query since a key lookup is performed anyway.
A side suggestion would be to create indexes on the #temp tables. Also the retrieval of the mDJDoctorsSpeciality & mDJDoctorsSpecialtyAbove (the set of 4 table outer-joins) is used twice in the batch. Wouldn't the first execution satisfy the second(returned resultset?), so why not store it and use the #temp table instead of querying the tables again (caveat: have not looked at the query logic/model at all, only at the plans) . Most likely, the queries could be nested (inner joins), something like:

```
from mDJDoctors [rd]   WITH (NOLOCK)
left join 
(
dbo.[mDJDoctorsSpeciality] [rs]  WITH (NOLOCK) 
join dbo.mDJSpecialtyCategory [rca]  WITH (NOLOCK) on rca.SpecialtyId = rs.specialId and rca.CategoryId in (4,8,840,779,10,813,3,18,7,918)
) on rd.DoctorID = rs.doctorId
left join 
(
dbo.mDJDoctorsSpecialtyAbove [ars]  WITH (NOLOCK) 
join dbo.mDJSpecialtyAboveCategory [arca]  WITH (NOLOCK) on arca.AboveSpecialtyId = ars.SpecialtyAboveId and arca.CategoryId in (4,8,840,779,10,813,3,18,7,918)
) on ars.doctorId = rd.DoctorID
where rs.doctorId is not null or rd.DoctorID is not null
```

on a second thought, isn't this a union?

```
(
DoctorId from dbo.mDJSpecialtyCategory....
union
DoctorId from dbo.mDJSpecialtyAboveCategory....
) as X
join mDJDoctors [rd] on DoctorId....
```

Comment: yes i use union insted of left join and the result is : sql 2012: from 26 ms to 16 ms and in sql 2017 from 26 ms to 9ms. tanx

Comment: so, what is the overall performance gain (after the index and the union)? you could still improve the retrieval of mConsultationQuestionsReplies by using cross apply (select top (@maxcount) .. from bo.mConsultationQuestionsReplies [r]... order by t.ReplyDateInsert DESC) == for each doctor/userid get only the top(maxcount) of replies.

Comment: i create this index  [missing_index_9245_9243] and there was better result but i dont know how mach. the new result is 2012 :878 ms and sql 2017 : 114 ms

Comment: let me add cross apply

Comment: i need to take @maxCount for each  cid, and userid . can you explain more . i dont know how use cross apply for this

Answer (score 0):

If I would be in your situation I would first look at the differences between the 2 instances; there are a lot of things that can impact performance of a query, just looking at the code is not enough in your case (running the same query on 2 separate instances).

So, take a look at the memory allocated to each instance, the settings (MAXDOP and CTP are a good start), are they running on the same machine? If not, are there any significant HW differences? Is there more usage (other people or applications running queries) of your SQL Server 2017 than your SQL Server 2012? Do you have the same amount of data on both servers? Are your indexes the same and are they maintained on both instances (could it be that you have a high level of fragmentation on your SQL Server 2017)? Also, take a look at the execution plans to see if they are identical on both servers.

I know it seems like a lot of questions, but without knowing the full context is hard to answer; any of the above could be the culprit for the slowness.

Comment: Not to mention that the CE (Cardinality Estimator) and the Query Optimizer have been updated and improved in later versions of SQL Server, so that's another very likely place your query is getting performance improvements from. Some databases get the performance benefit just by being moved to a newer version instance and having their compatibility level changed to the newest available value.

Comment: tanx for your answer , i will check every matters you mention tomorrow. and i will be answering  all of them . plz help me this is important to me

Comment: no the HW  is same 12 gb ram and core i 3 cpu both of them are in the same situation

Comment: Is there more usage (other people or applications running queries) of your SQL Server 2017 than your SQL Server 2012? Do you have the same amount of data on both servers? answer is no

Comment: Do you have the same amount of data on both servers? yes i did a sql data compare

Comment: Are your indexes the same and are they maintained on both instances (could it be that you have a high level of fragmentation on your SQL Server 2017)? answer : how can i check that ??

Comment: take a look at the execution plans to see if they are identical on both servers. answer : i added execution plan can you check it for me , i am no professional

Comment: You find a nice query to check your indexes here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Check-SQL-Server-a-a5758043. Just make sure to be connected to your DB when you run the query.